# Removing a matching string item from a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array, filter

I have a multi dimensional array derived from checkbox values, they can have the same strings for all instances of the outer array.

Example Array:

```
[
    ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
    ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
    ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
]
```

When I call the function, I am passing an index number which represents which one of the inner arrays I want to address. For instance, if the user **unchecked** the checkbox representing 'Two' in the 1 index, I'd want the multi dimensional array to change to this.

```
 [
        ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
        ['One', 'Three'],
        ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
 ]
```

I am having trouble writing this function. This is in React and the snippet to address this is currently like this:

```
setCheckedValues(prevArray => {
          const newItemArray = prevArray.slice()
          const newItemArrayFiltered = [...newItemArray, newItemArray[index].filter(name => name !== event.target.name)]
          return newItemArrayFiltered
        })
```

I've searched a lot and am stuck as to how to remove a string in only one of the inner arrays. Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fairly standard way to handle this is to `slice()` around the index.

```
setCheckedValues(prevArray => {
  return [
    ...prevArray.slice(0, index),
    prevArray[index].filter(name => name !== event.target.name),
    ...prevArray.slice(index + 1)
  ];
});
```

With an alternative being to `map()` over the array checking for the matching index and returning the updated value appropriately.

```
setCheckedValues(prevArray => prevArray
  .map((arr, i) =>
    i === index
      ? arr.filter(name => name !== event.target.name)
      : arr
  )
);
```